# How to make IOS picker view to select a specific value by default

Tags: ios, native, selection, uipickerview

I'm getting an issue on a picker view. When the picker is opened I would like the focus to be on the active value that is 70 instead of 42. I have used generic attribute like `selected` for this purpose but no luck.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML3q6.png)

Any idea how to solve this please?
Thanks

Comment: May be some useful info [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/pickers-in-forms)

Answer (score 0):

you can set the default selected value by the following method. (in below code, 1 is the index of the row you want to select)

```
picker.selectRow(1, inComponent:0, animated:true)
```